# Disable default sorting in itables pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am learning how to use tablets in Jupyter notebook. To test, I made a small data frame;

```
from itables import init_notebook_mode

init_notebook_mode(all_interactive=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "review": [
        "awesome sound quality. pros 7-8 hrs of battery life (including 45 mins approx call time)Awesome sound output. Bass and treble are really very clear without equaliser. With equaliser, sound wary depends on the handset sound quality.Weightless to carry and in head tooMic is good, but in traffic it is not too good (3.25/5)3.5mm Option is really important to mention. Really expecting other leading brands to implement this.ConsVery tight in ears. adjusters are ok .. this ll be very tight...READ MORE",
        "I think it is such a good product not only as per the quality but also the design is quite good . I m using this product from January ... In this pandamic situation it has became the most useful and helpful . Overall the bass and the sound quality is pretty good and another thing that will give you such a sigh of relief that it will provide a wire that will help you in case of lacking charges.READ MORE",
        "bad quality",
        "good sound",
    ],
}
)
```

But when I sample first couple of rows say;

```
df2["review"][0:3]
```

we see following output in this order. plz see screenshot. Is it possible to disable default sorting behavior and see data as it is. Help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: update your pandas ~ or create with order dict ~ the sort happened when you create your dict~

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. But I am not sure it is because of dictionary definition. I have added two screenshots with updated pandas info. Even when I read the csv file , I am facing same issue.